# Is there any way to customize the Windows 7 taskbar auto-hide behavior? Delay activation? Timer?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I'm becoming increasingly frustrated with the way Windows 7 handles showing a hidden taskbar. It's incredibly over-eager to pop out and obscure what I'm *really* trying to interact with, requiring me to move the mouse away, wait for it to auto-hide again, then resume what I was doing but more deliberately.

After closely examining the behavior, it appears that a hidden taskbar "peeks out" from the edge by 2 or 3 pixels, and slowly moving your mouse into this area activates it; you don't even need to touch the edge of the screen.

I would love it if there was a way to customize or change this behavior. Ideally, the taskbar would only pop out if you are actively "pushing" the edge of the screen it is hidden on. So activation only occurs once you've reached the screens edge and continue to move the mouse past a customizable threshold.

Alternatively, a simple activation delay would suffice as well. So only if the mouse remains in that 2-3 pixel area (a.k.a. *on* the taskbar) for greater than a customizable amount of time does it pop out again. This would only be a fraction of a second. Often times the cursor simply "careens" off the edge of the screen while trying to focus on something nearby.

Anyway, if there are any registry settings or utilities that can achieve either of these effects, that would be great! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: [Taskbar Activate](http://home.nordnet.fr/~pmdevigne/TaskbarActivate.html).

> Manage the way taskbar window is displayed on the screen :
>
> - displayed or hidden are directly managed by Taskbar Activate.
> - delayed activation when mouse is over.
> - force activation or not with "always on top" windows.
> - make the taskbar always reachable even with full-screen windows.
> - works with dynamic screen resolution change, moving the taskbar to
>     another edge of the screen , Windows 98 multi-monitor.
> - show a highlight line when mouse is over.
> - manage also others Windows bars.
> - it can be temporary suspended.
> - you can have the taskbar completely hidden (no more one line at the
>     bottom of the screen).
> - you can choose the color for hilighting when you go over the
>     taskbar.
> - you can stop managing one bar if there is a problem with it.
> - even more options.

Comment: That is very cool. Never knew it existed.

Comment: Jjejej :), just mark the question as answered :P 

see you

Comment: @DiegoMak: Does it work with Windows 7?

Comment: I try this with windows 7 home premium x32

Comment: Calbar this was the solution for your problem??  If yes, Please Mark this question as answered. Just click on check image in the left of this post.

Comment: Awesome, this works great!

I was concerned about compatibility with Windows 7, especially 64-bit, but I can confirm it *does* work.

I did notice one quirky behavior, however... if you select the "Get back the bar in the background..." option, which basically hides those 2-3 pixels that stick out, it seems to leave the Start button behind when it auto-hides... It looks like a desktop icon and maintains full start-menu functionality! If it didn't seem so glitchy, I might consider it a feature :P.

Anyway, you can still use the app perfectly fine without that option selected.

Thanks again!

Comment: Does anyone else notice that the Link is dead? It goes to a Blue Host page and there is no data.

Comment: Here is a new link to Taskbar activate... http://home.nordnet.fr/~pmdevigne/TaskbarActivate.html  (that was the software DiegoMak was pointing to, wasn't it?)

Comment: Buggy in win 7.

Answer (score 2):

Try this application instead: [Taskbar Activate](http://pmdevigne.free.fr/TaskbarActivate.html).

This worked for me on Windows 7 x64. I disabled all the settings except for the following:

1. Delayed activation of the taskbar (200ms)
2. Restart the delay when mouse moves
3. Go over 'always on top' windows.

Comment: Just using the options mentioned before removes the coloured line that seems buggy. Also setting a higher delay 600-800ms for me, still allows you to click the appropriate part of the screen to release the taskbar. <3

Comment: Very useful. I initially tried Taskbar Activate on Win7 x64 but had dismissed it as buggy, but on trying these settings, it works like a charm. Thanks, friend.

Comment: I had tried using Taskbar Activate with Classic Shell on Windows 7 and had dismissed as buggy.  I thought I would try again with these settings and it works perfectly with Classic Shell!!!  Thanks!!